# DateTime.ParseExact does not recognize string as valid 

Tags: .net, parsing, datetime

I know this one is already has so many kind of similarity. But, it makes me confused everytime I am converting the date on the different date. The message `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` always shown.

I have try some of this code:

```
Dim EffectiveDate As DateTime

EffectiveDate  = DateTime.ParseExact("05/08/2012", "MM/dd/yyyy", Nothing)
EffectiveDate  = DateTime.ParseExact("5/8/2012", "MM/dd/yyyy", Nothing)
EffectiveDate  = DateTime.ParseExact("1/10/2012", "MM/dd/yyyy", Nothing)
EffectiveDate  = DateTime.ParseExact("10/1/2012", "MM/dd/yyyy", Nothing)
//It resulted in got the message above

EffectiveDate  = DateTime.ParseExact("10/10/2012", "MM/dd/yyyy", Nothing)
//It has no problem
```

What's wrong with the code?? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime.Parse()` should work just fine in most cases, unless you want users to use a specific format.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The date parameter must be in the exact format specified.  Your format is MM/dd/yyyy, yet you provided a date of 10/1/2012.  This date has 1 digit for the day, you specified 2 digits for the day.  See the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Comment: But why when I tried "05/08/2012", it resulted on got the message, and when I tried "10/10/2012" it has no problem? Doesn't it on the same format "MM/dd/yyyy"?

Answer (score 0):

check web.config's globalization tag
it should be like this

```
> <globalization requestEncoding="windows-1252"
> responseEncoding="windows-1252" culture="en-GB"/>
```

which by default comes in american culture...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know if there will be one or two digits, use a single letter in the format string. In your case

```
"M/d/yyyy"
```

When you use `Nothing` as format provider, the interpretation of `/` in the format string depends on the date separator of the current culture.